# What is the different ways to create an object to a class

Tags: c#

What is the difference between below two ways of creating object to a class

```
Class1 class1object = new Class1(); and

var Class1object  = new Class1();
```

Comment: They produce identical output from the compiler

Answer (score 1):

nothing. 'var' is a compiler construct that works out what class type you meant to type out. For the majority of the time, its simply a shortcut to typing out the explicit class name.

In both cases, you will have a `Class1` object, that was created using `new Class1()`

Comment: You might want to add that you can do `Class1 c;` but not `var c;`